# Exception, but only on 3rd time - The IAsyncResult object was not returned from the corresponding asynchronous method on this class

Tags: sockets, exception, delegates, tcpclient, iasyncresult

I have a legacy (2008) Windows service application (using System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase) that I need to utilize in a slightly different way to how it's working now. At the moment it starts up and creates a TCPLISTENER on a specific port, for a client app to connect to (which it does once) in order to send/receive requests to the listening port. This all works fine. However, the adaptation requires use of a web app to connect to the listener port, then send/rcv as normal but after the receive it must DISCONNECT(*)

(* - if the web app didn't have to disconnect from the listening socket after each test that'd be better, but how I might achieve this is beyond me. Can I keep a TCP connection in session state for re-use?)

Anyway, the adaptation all works fine for the first **TWO** connect/send/rcv/disconnect tests but on the **THIRD** the service throws an ArgumentException in the EndAccept of the Socket class.

I don't understand why it is failing on the 3rd test.

---

Here is the simple test client.

```vb
      Public Class ConnectDisconnectTCP
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private IP As String = "127.0.0.1"
    Private port As Int32 = 10002
    Private mTCP As System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
    Private netStrm As NetworkStream

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim oEnc As New ASCIIEncoding
        Dim ScanText As String = "100000000093001X" + vbLf
        Dim mTCP As System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient

        'connect and create a tcpclient
        mTCP = New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(IP, port)
        netStrm = mTCP.GetStream()
        netStrm.WriteAsync(oEnc.GetBytes(ScanText.ToString), 0, ScanText.ToString.Length)

        If netStrm.CanRead Then

            Dim myReadBuffer(1024) As Byte
            Dim myCompleteMessage As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
            Dim numberOfBytesRead As Integer = 0

            ' Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size.
            Do
                numberOfBytesRead = netStrm.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length)
                myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead))
            Loop While netStrm.DataAvailable

        End If

       'CLOSE
        netStrm.Close()
        mTCP.Close() 'Disposes this TcpClient instance and requests that the underlying TCP connection be closed.
        mTCP = Nothing
        Label1.Text = "Closed"
    End Sub End Class
```

---

And here is the TCPListener class on the service that does all the work

```or-tag-here
   Imports System
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Net
    Imports System.Net.Sockets
    Imports System.Threading
    Imports System.Text

    Public Class TCPListenerPort

    Private currentAsynchResult As IAsyncResult
    Private cState As ClientState
    Private servSock As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
    Private m_connectionstate As Int32 = 0
    Dim sData As String = String.Empty

    'counters
    Public cnt As Int32 = 0
    Public rcvcnt As Int32 = 0
    Public acccnt As Int32 = 0
    Public sndcnt As Int32 = 0
    Public sndcal As Int32 = 0
    Public cncnt As Int32 = 0

    'Public Events
    Public Event ConnectionState(ByVal enmState As Int32)
    Public Event DataArrived(ByVal strData As Object)

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal dr As DataRow)

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        Try
            If Not cState Is Nothing Then
                cState.ClntSock.Close()
            End If
            If Not servSock Is Nothing Then
                servSock.Close()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            MyBase.Finalize()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Class ClientState

        Public Const BUFSIZE As Integer = 1024

        Public mrcvBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(BUFSIZE - 1) {}
        Public mSendBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(BUFSIZE - 1) {}

        Private mclntSock As Socket = Nothing


        Public Sub New(ByRef clntSock As Socket)
            mclntSock = clntSock
            ReDim mrcvBuffer(BUFSIZE)
            ReDim mSendBuffer(BUFSIZE)
        End Sub

        Public ReadOnly Property SckConnected() As Boolean
            Get
                SckConnected = mclntSock.Connected
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property RcvBuffer() As Byte()
            Get
                RcvBuffer = mrcvBuffer
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property SendBuffer() As Byte()
            Get
                SendBuffer = mSendBuffer
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property ClntSock() As Socket
            Get
                ClntSock = mclntSock
            End Get
        End Property

    End Class

    Public Sub Connect(ByVal TCPPort As Int32, ByVal Backlog As Int32)



        Try
            cState = New ClientState(servSock)
            cState.ClntSock.Bind(New IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, TCPPort))
            cState.ClntSock.Listen(100) '5

            While True
                cncnt = cncnt + 1
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("in connect WHILE " + cncnt.ToString)
                currentAsynchResult = servSock.BeginAccept(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AcceptCallback), cState)
                currentAsynchResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()
            End While

        Catch __unusedObjectDisposedException1__ As ObjectDisposedException
        Catch e As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub AcceptCallback(ByVal asyncResult As IAsyncResult)


        Try

            acccnt = acccnt + 1
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AcceptCallback Start" + acccnt.ToString)

            'obtain the Socket on which the connection attempt is being made
            Dim servSock As ClientState = asyncResult.AsyncState 'Asyncstate gets a user defined object that qualifies or contains info about an async operation
            Dim clntSock As Socket

            clntSock = servSock.ClntSock.EndAccept(asyncResult)

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(clntSock.RemoteEndPoint)

            Dim cs As New ClientState(clntSock)
            clntSock.BeginReceive(cs.RcvBuffer, 0, cs.RcvBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback), cs)

        Catch ar As ArgumentException

            '!!!!!Test 3 errors here with
            'The IAsyncResult object was not returned from the corresponding asynchronous method on this class.

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AcceptCallback End " + acccnt.ToString)

    End Sub

    Private Sub ReceiveCallback(ByVal asyncResult As IAsyncResult)
        rcvcnt = rcvcnt + 1
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ReceiveCallback In " + rcvcnt.ToString)
        Dim cs As ClientState = asyncResult.AsyncState
        Dim AE As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
        Dim recvMsgSize As Int32 = 0
        Dim strTmp As String = String.Empty
        Dim strSend As String = String.Empty

        Try

            recvMsgSize = cs.ClntSock.EndReceive(asyncResult)
            strTmp = Replace(AE.GetString(cs.RcvBuffer), vbNullChar, "")
            If recvMsgSize > 0 Then
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ReceiveCallback receiveMsgSize " + recvMsgSize.ToString)
                If Right(strTmp, 1) = vbLf Or Right(strTmp, 1) = vbCr Then
                    strSend = sData + strTmp
                    strSend = strSend.Replace(vbLf, "")
                    strSend = strSend.Replace(vbCr, "")
                    cState = cs
                    sData = String.Empty

                    RaiseEvent DataArrived(strSend)
                Else

                End If

            Else

            End If


        Catch ex As Exception

            Throw ex
        End Try

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ReceiveCallback Exit " + rcvcnt.ToString)

    End Sub

    Public Function SendData(ByVal strData As Object) As Boolean

        ' Change the data to a byte array if necessary, then send it via the socket
        Dim oEncoder As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
        Dim bytes As Byte()
        Dim Result As IAsyncResult

        Try

            Select Case strData.GetType().ToString
                Case "System.String" ' Convert a string to a byte array
                    bytes = oEncoder.GetBytes(strData)
                Case "System.Byte[]" ' Send a byte array directly
                    bytes = strData
                Case Else ' And just send anything else as-is
                    bytes = strData
            End Select

            sndcnt = sndcnt + 1
            Result = cState.ClntSock.BeginSend(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf SendCallback), cState)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SendData " + sndcnt + " " + Result.ToString)

            Result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
        Return True

    End Function

    Private Sub SendCallback(ByVal asyncResult As IAsyncResult)

        Dim cs As ClientState = asyncResult.AsyncState
        Dim bytesSent As Int32 = 0

        Try
            bytesSent = cs.ClntSock.EndSend(asyncResult)
            sndcal = sndcal + 1

            cs.ClntSock.BeginReceive(cs.RcvBuffer, 0, cs.RcvBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback), cs)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SendCallBack " + sndcal.ToString + " " + bytesSent.ToString)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw (ex)
        End Try

    End Sub


    End Class
```

---

With .net trace on, plus the code's system diagnostics debug.write, here is a complete log of the TEST1, TEST2, TEST3/CRASH operation. Note the '<-- SCANTEXT RECEIVED' and '<-- RESPONSE RECEIVED' annotations. The 'in connect WHILE 4' annotation shows the arrival of the 3rd request attempt.

```
    [12572] TcpClient#57416410::TcpClient(AddressFamily#2)
    [12572] Socket#61940669::Socket(AddressFamily#2)
    [12572] Exiting Socket#61940669::Socket() 
    [12572] Exiting TcpClient#57416410::TcpClient() 
    [12572] TcpClient#57416410::TcpClient()
    [12572] Exiting TcpClient#57416410::TcpClient() 
    [12572] Socket#15193904::Socket(AddressFamily#2)
    [12572] Exiting Socket#15193904::Socket() 
    [17872] Socket#40528290::Socket(AddressFamily#2)
    [17872] Exiting Socket#40528290::Socket() 
    [17872] Socket#40528290::Bind(0.0.0.0:10002#10002)
    [17872] Exiting Socket#40528290::Bind() 
    [17872] Socket#40528290::Listen(Int32#100)
    [17872] Exiting Socket#40528290::Listen() 
    in connect WHILE 1
    [17872] Socket#40528290::BeginAccept()
    [17872] Exiting Socket#40528290::BeginAccept()  -> AcceptAsyncResult#515737
    The thread '1' (0x6674) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The thread '<No Name>' (0x1df8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The thread '<No Name>' (0x5dac) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    [7984] Socket#49538252::Socket()
    [7984] Exiting Socket#49538252::Socket() 
    in connect WHILE 2
    AcceptCallback Start1
    [17872] Socket#40528290::BeginAccept()
    [7984] Socket#40528290::EndAccept(AcceptAsyncResult#515737)
    [17872] Exiting Socket#40528290::BeginAccept()  -> AcceptAsyncResult#27334100
    System.Net.Sockets Information: 0 : [7984] Socket#49538252 - Accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:63817 to 127.0.0.1:10002.
    [7984] Exiting Socket#40528290::EndAccept()     -> Socket#49538252
    127.0.0.1:63817
    [7984] Socket#49538252::BeginReceive()
    [7984] Exiting Socket#49538252::BeginReceive()  -> OverlappedAsyncResult#62696216
    AcceptCallback End 1
    [22168] Data from Socket#49538252::PostCompletion
    [22168] 00000000 : 32 30 30 30 30 30 30 30-30 30 38 33 30 30 31 58 : 100000000093001X <-- SCANTEXT RECEIVED, TEST1
    [22168] 00000010 : 0A                                              : .
    ReceiveCallback In 1
    [22168] Socket#49538252::EndReceive(OverlappedAsyncResult#62696216)
    [22168] Exiting Socket#49538252::EndReceive()   -> Int32#17
    ReceiveCallback receiveMsgSize 17
    [22168] Socket#49538252::BeginSend()
    [22168] Exiting Socket#49538252::BeginSend()    -> OverlappedAsyncResult#13462887
    A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
    [19228] Data from Socket#49538252::PostCompletion
    [19228] 00000000 : 07                                              : . <-- RESPONSE RECEIVED, TEST1
    [19228] Socket#49538252::EndSend(OverlappedAsyncResult#13462887)
    [19228] Exiting Socket#49538252::EndSend()  -> Int32#1
    [19228] Socket#49538252::BeginReceive()
    [19228] Exiting Socket#49538252::BeginReceive()     -> OverlappedAsyncResult#25961440
    SendCallBack 1 1
    [7984] Data from Socket#49538252::PostCompletion
    [7984] 00000000 :                                                 : 
    ReceiveCallback In 2
    [7984] Socket#49538252::EndReceive(OverlappedAsyncResult#25961440)
    [7984] Exiting Socket#49538252::EndReceive()    -> Int32#0
    ReceiveCallback Exit 2
    ReceiveCallback Exit 2
    [22168] Socket#31352595::Socket()
    [22168] Exiting Socket#31352595::Socket() 
    AcceptCallback Start2
    in connect WHILE 3
    [17872] Socket#40528290::BeginAccept()
    [22168] Socket#40528290::EndAccept(AcceptAsyncResult#27334100)
    [17872] Exiting Socket#40528290::BeginAccept()  -> AcceptAsyncResult#39421196
    System.Net.Sockets Information: 0 : [22168] Socket#31352595 - Accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:63820 to 127.0.0.1:10002.
    [22168] Exiting Socket#40528290::EndAccept()    -> Socket#31352595
    127.0.0.1:63820
    [22168] Socket#31352595::BeginReceive()
    [22168] Exiting Socket#31352595::BeginReceive()     -> OverlappedAsyncResult#28002689
    AcceptCallback End 2
    [7984] Data from Socket#31352595::PostCompletion
    [7984] 00000000 : 32 30 30 30 30 30 30 30-30 30 38 33 30 30 31 58 : 100000000093001X <-- SCANTEXT RECEIVED, TEST2
    [7984] 00000010 : 0A                                              : .
    ReceiveCallback In 3
    [7984] Socket#31352595::EndReceive(OverlappedAsyncResult#28002689)
    [7984] Exiting Socket#31352595::EndReceive()    -> Int32#17
    ReceiveCallback receiveMsgSize 17
    [7984] Socket#31352595::BeginSend()
    [7984] Exiting Socket#31352595::BeginSend()     -> OverlappedAsyncResult#31071611
    [22168] Data from Socket#31352595::PostCompletion
    A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
    [22168] 00000000 : 07                                              : . <-- RESULT RECEIVED, TEST2
    [22168] Socket#31352595::EndSend(OverlappedAsyncResult#31071611)
    [22168] Exiting Socket#31352595::EndSend()  -> Int32#1
    [22168] Socket#31352595::BeginReceive()
    [22168] Exiting Socket#31352595::BeginReceive()     -> OverlappedAsyncResult#51673536
    SendCallBack 2 1
    [4640] Data from Socket#31352595::PostCompletion
    [4640] 00000000 :                                                 : 
    ReceiveCallback Exit 3
    The thread '<No Name>' (0x4b1c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    ReceiveCallback In 4
    [4640] Socket#31352595::EndReceive(OverlappedAsyncResult#51673536)
    [4640] Exiting Socket#31352595::EndReceive()    -> Int32#0
    ReceiveCallback Exit 4
    [4640] Socket#37088038::Socket()
    [4640] Exiting Socket#37088038::Socket() 
    AcceptCallback Start3
    [4640] Socket#49538252::EndAccept(AcceptAsyncResult#39421196)
    in connect WHILE 4
    [17872] Socket#40528290::BeginAccept()
    [17872] Exiting Socket#40528290::BeginAccept()  -> AcceptAsyncResult#8948635
    //ERROR THROWN HERE
    AcceptCallback End 3
```

---

**Monitoring with netstat**

When the service is started, this appears, indicating the service is listening on port 10002

```
    TCP    0.0.0.0:10002 LON-WKS-ZER01:0      LISTENING
```

On the 1st and 2nd scans (ie successful) everything works fine. The test web app connects, sends 'scantext', various callback delegates are fired, and we get a good reply.

Netstat during the 1st test, after the connection is made :

```
    TCP    0.0.0.0:10002          LON-WKS-ZER01:0      LISTENING
    TCP    127.0.0.1:10002        apps:59574             ESTABLISHED
    TCP    127.0.0.1:59574        apps:10002             ESTABLISHED
```

(then scan #1 is completed)

When testApp mTCP.Close() called, the status changes to CLOSE_WAIT and FIN_WAIT_2

```
   TCP    0.0.0.0:10002          LON-WKS-ZER01:0      LISTENING
   TCP    127.0.0.1:10002        apps:59574             CLOSE_WAIT
   TCP    127.0.0.1:59574        apps:10002             FIN_WAIT_2
```

A few mins later, the CLOSE and FIN connections disappear but still have the LISTENER

```
 TCP    0.0.0.0:10002          LON-WKS-ZER01:0      LISTENING
```

Next, send scan#2, it repeats the sequence as above, with a successful result.

On the third scan, when it attempts to make a new connection, the exception is thrown in AcceptCallback on this line :

```
clntSock = servSock.ClntSock.EndAccept(asyncResult)
```

Specifically, it's an ArgumentException, 'asyncResult was not created by a call to BeginAccept' (see [EndAccept](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdee4kd7(v=vs.110).aspx))

So, for reasons I can't quite fathom, the IASyncResult of the 3rd test is causing the EndAccept method to throw an ArgumentException.

To summarise the bug - the Connect call's BeginAccept sets up a delegate for AcceptCallback and passes an IASyncResult. The AcceptCallBacks EndAccept throws an ArgumentException

I realise the way things are being done are not very up to date and we'd be better off with something else, but with one thing and another (time, resource) I need to try and make the slight adaptation work. But I don't understand why (existing client app) CONNECT, scan,scan,scan,scan etc works, but (web app) CONNECT,scan,DISCONNECT, CONNECT, scan, DISCONNECT fails on the THIRD scan's CONNECT

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? I hit something similar (also ArgumentException on EndAccept but each time and with a different message). For me it helped to use the overload of BeginAccept that takes a maximum size. Any size would do. It then would pass EndAccept just fine and deliver the expected data with BeginReceive-EndReceive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar issue raised and answered [here](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/argumentexception-iasyncresult-object-was-not-returned-from-the-corresponding.1227010/)

> ... you are holding the socket object in a class-scoped variable. So, if
>   somehow the socket gets disconnected while the ReadCallback is
>   executing and you reconnect it (thereby changing the socket object) -
>   now they don't match, you are trying to complete the Async request
>   using the new object when the old one is the one actually completing.

In your case it is the variable `cState`. On `Connect` method, if you just declare a new instance of `cState` locally which holds the socket then the error may stops occuring.

```
Dim clientState As  New ClientState(servSock)
clientState.ClntSock.Bind(New IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, TCPPort))
clientState.ClntSock.Listen(Backlog)

While True
    Dim result As IAsyncResult = servSock.BeginAccept(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AcceptCallback), clientState)
    result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()
End While
```

And also, `mTCP` should be disposed on the client side.